How to retrieve lost terminal in VSC remote SSH
I use VSC as editor and have opened a remote connection to my Debian server via SSH in VSC.
I work there on a Node.js project. I have started in VSC a terminal and there started my Node.js server with the command npm start.
Now my issue:
Sometimes I kill the terminal in VSC accidently. Then, the Nodejs server is still running in the background. Therefore, I'm not able to stop the NodeJS server anymore, or see the output, I've had in the previously opened Terminal.
The only way to stop the NodeJS server I've found is, to open htop, and kill all vscode-server processes. Then reconnect the SSH session in VSC, open a new terminal and start the Nodejs Server again.
Is there any method to retrieve the "lost" terminal again, to avoid this cumbersome process?

Usually one uses tools like screen or tmux to allow a terminal to continue in the event of a disconnect.

Seconding Ouroborus. First thing after connecting is to screen, then work in the screen session. On a disconnect, the screen session can be trivially recovered by reconnecting and running screen -r.

Hi @Ouroborus and @DevSolar. Thanks for the recommendation. Sorry, I've forgot to mention screen. Okay. Sure, I can do it with this. I was not sure if this is just a workaround or if there's a functionality within VSC, which I was missing. Okay, then screen it is. Thank you.

You may be able to configure VSC to issue a command immediately after connecting to an SSH session. If so, there are options for screen to connect to a named screen session and to create it if it doesn't already exist.

Hi, that's also good idea. Although, it isn't so often that I close the terminal accidently, that I need to automate the reconnect with screen -r. Although, it's a smart approach. Maybe I implement it, when I close the terminal to often. Thank you for the idea.
